# x264 stream - no video output

Tags: video, ffmpeg, x264

I've got a RTMP server with ffmpeg attached to it, encoding the input to x264 and segmenting it into HLS.

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/publish/R6rPCgHpT0OTuqC5hbc6GQ_vdV8UmAPS-CStRP7H+Ew2g_1_15 -vsync 0 -acodec aac -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -profile baseline -tune zerolatency -f hls -hls_segment_filename "R6rPCgHpT0OTuqC5hbc6GQ_vdV8UmAPS-CStRP7H+Ew2g_1-source-%03d.ts" -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_playlist_type event -progress /var/media/R6rPCgHpT0OTuqC5hbc6GQ/progress_R6rPCgHpT0OTuqC5hbc6GQ_vdV8UmAPS-CStRP7H+Ew2g_1.log /var/media/R6rPCgHpT0OTuqC5hbc6GQ/s1_vdV8UmAPS-CStRP7H+Ew2g/source/out.m3u8
```

It works just fine for some broadcasters, while for others it either outputs just the audio, or the video output is choppy - hangs once in a while on a single frame.

What's even more surprising - for those experiencing blank screen issue, it doesn't always happen, and their broadcasting setup work just fine on Twitch, Mixer or any other broadcasting service. (they all broadcast in x264)

Here I include report files:

Blank video w/ audio:
https://pastebin.com/8AqRX8wZ

Choppy video output w/ good quality audio:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/patrykcieszkowski/ffmpeg_debugger/master/report_ldCOrttdSFW0FtUab6UeAQ_RUX4M%2BUEQpi2aycfi8Vq0g_1.log

Answer (score 1):

As per the report, no video stream was detected during input probe.

The video stream was encountered late, i.e.

```
[flv @ 0x555af06f6c80] New video stream 0:1 at pos:151353 and DTS:8.332s
```

You can try to work around this by increasing probe parameters

```
ffmpeg -analyzeduration 15M -probesize 10M -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/publish/R6rPCgHpT0OTuqC5hbc6GQ_vdV8UmAPS-CStRP7H+Ew2g_1_15 ...
```

Comment: Thanks @Gyan, I'll definitely try out those parameters. I've added to my question another log file, for a stream with both; audio + video, but the video hangs as described above. Can you please have a look?

Comment: For the 2nd scenario, let ffmpeg run for a few minutes and then terminate. The new log is from a running process, so it doesn't have some useful information printed at process termination. Add `-v 40` to the command.